# Subquery on a join

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1248

I'm trying to do a query to filter on rows from one table and then join the results on another table and then filter out additional rows.

Here is the query I've written:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT media.id AS id2, media.flagged AS flagged2, media.item_status AS status2 
          FROM media 
         WHERE flagged2 != 'nsfw' 
           AND status2 != 'deleted' 
     ORDER BY id2 DESC LIMIT 0,5) 
  JOIN media on info.mid = media.id 
 WHERE info.topic = 'food_drink' 
    OR info.topic='cooking' 
GROUP BY info.mid
```

I think I'm pretty close to getting the query working but I keep getting the message, "Every derived table must have its own alias." I've Googled this and from what I've read I need to alias parts of the subquery which I've tried but I still can't get it working.

Comment: just a quick question...where did you get the "info"? is it an alias or a table?

Comment: @hallie: Given that Eric hasn't used table aliases, I believe it's a table.  Eric is going to have to let us know if references to `INFO` should be in this query, otherwise how they relate to the derived table...

Comment: I suspect that ...JOIN media on info.mid = media.id... should actually be ...JOIN **info** on info.mid = media.id...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT media.id AS id2, media.flagged AS flagged2, media.item_status AS status2 
          FROM media 
         WHERE flagged2 != 'nsfw' 
           AND status2 != 'deleted' 
      ORDER BY id2 DESC LIMIT 0, 5) x
  JOIN media on info.mid = media.id 
 WHERE info.topic = 'food_drink' 
    OR info.topic='cooking' 
GROUP BY info.mid
```

See the `x`, just outside the bracket but before the join?  That's what the error is about.  The stuff inside the brackets after FROM and before JOIN is a derived table (AKA inline view), and MySQL requires that you specify a table alias for it.  Then, when you reference any columns from inside it, you'd use `x.id2`/etc.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I thought the part I had to alias was in the subquery. Just rewrote the query based on your input and it's working perfectly!